# Is an overridden pure virtual function, virtual?

Tags: c++, overriding, virtual, pure-virtual

Below you will see 3 classes. **My question** is why can I use `override` on the `getArea()` of the `FunnySquare` Class, even though it is **not tagged as virtual** in the `Square` Class.

My assumption is that an overridden pure virtual function is virtual even though it is not specified, but I am not sure that is true and could not find any references to confirm.

```
class Shape {
  public:
  virtual float getArea() = 0;
};

class Square : public Shape {
  private:
  float length;

  public:
  Square(float len){
    length = len;
  }
  float getArea() override {
    return length * length; 
  }

  void sayHi() {cout << "hell0" << endl;}
};

class FunnySquare : public Square {
  public:
  FunnySquare(float len) : Square(len) {}
  void tellJoke() {std::cout << "I gave you the wrong area haha" << endl;} 
  
  float getArea() override {
    return 2.0;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both `Square::getArea` and `FunnySquare::getArea` are [`virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) too.

(emphasis mine)

> Then this function in the class Derived is also virtual (**whether or not the keyword virtual is used in its declaration**) and overrides Base::vf (whether or not the word override is used in its declaration).

Comment: Which, btw. is one of the many things I *HATE* about C++.  Nothing in the the source code should ever be "implicit".  If a function is "virtual", the language should *require* you to say "virtual".  If a variable is an "object", you should always specify "()" when you construct an instance.  And don't get me started on how C++11 hijacked the keyword "auto"...